# Element-wise inverse of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a column vector $X = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$.

How do I manipulated it to get a row vector $Z = (\frac{1}{x_1}, \cdots, \frac{1}{x_n})$?

Comment: You can accomplish similar things to the Hadamard Product, and this could be described as [Hadamard Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations) (*after transposition*).

Comment: @JMoravitz: Thanks so much! It helped!